# Get the resut from facebook in asp.net mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a asp.net MVC site and in that I have a user search functionality. I want that I should get the search result from facebook too if there is a user with name typed in search box. In search I want the user photo and Full name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get this info back for the logged in user using Graph API or FQL. For your ASP.net app, you should do the search server-side so it appears in-line in your other search results. Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ for a description of the server-side authentication flow. Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends for some examples on how to get a list of friends for the logged-in user. Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends?fields=picture